# Why are 32-bit mips instructions stored in 64-bit space?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

MIPS 32 uses instructions of 32 bits. But when almost all instructions are done, the CPU adds +4 to the PC. As far as I know, 4 words means 64 bits, so, how can this be possible? Am I forgetting something or does mips32 wastes 2 empty words every instruction?

Comment: 4 words in MIPS is 4x32 = 128 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIPS is a Von Neumann architecture processes, and both instructions and data in it are addressed on byte and not word boundary. So the PC value is advanced by four bytes - the size of the instruction.

BTW, MIPS64 instructions are still 32-bit in size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how long are addresses? I mean, if the first instruction goes on #0000, the next one would go on #0004? So, each address represents 1 Byte?

Comment: The addresses themselves are either 32 or 64 bits; but a unit of addressing is one byte. So yeah, each possible address value points at a specific byte in memory (the memory may not be physically there, but that's another issue).

Comment: Hi Seva, thank you very much for your answer! Could you answer me another one? Using 32bits addresses, how is all the data accessed? As far as I know, the mips32 structure for lw only allows 16 bits for the address to load, which I guess can let you load from 0x000 to 0xFFFF. How could the 0xFFFFFFFF address be loaded?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev seva, in the last comment I forgot to place your name to notify you. If you know the answer and you could tell me, I would be very pleased to hear it! Thank you!

Comment: Igor's answer looks satisfactory to me.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I am refering to the question in the comment.

Comment: LW includes a base register and 16 bits of offset. The base register may contain the upper bits, 0xFFFF0000 in your example.